# Converting ConnectForm fields from ZeosLib to FireDAC

Tags: delphi, firedac, zeos

Delphi 10.2.2

**1.** Is this correct way to convert this [code part](https://github.com/Faq/Truice/blob/master/MeConnectForm.pas#L156) for MySQL from ZeosLib to FireDAC?

ZeosLib:

```
procedure TMeConnectForm.edExit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    MainForm.MyTrinityConnection.Password := edPassword.Text;
    MainForm.MyTrinityConnection.HostName := edServer.Text;
    MainForm.MyTrinityConnection.User := edUsername.Text;
    MainForm.MyTrinityConnection.Database := edmDatabase.Text;
    MainForm.MyTrinityConnection.Port := StrToIntDef(edPort.Text, 3306);
  except
    ActiveControl := Sender as TWinControl;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

FireDAC:

```
procedure TMeConnectForm.edExit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    MainForm.MyTrinityConnection.Open('Password := edPassword.Text');
    MainForm.MyTrinityConnection.Open('Server:= edServer.Text');
    MainForm.MyTrinityConnection.Open('User_Name:= edUsername.Text');
    MainForm.MyTrinityConnection.Open('Database:= edmDatabase.Text');
    MainForm.MyTrinityConnection.Open('Port:= StrToIntDef(edPort.Text, 3306)');
  except
    ActiveControl := Sender as TWinControl;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

**2.** Should somewhere here insert also this?

```
MainForm.MyTrinityConnection.DriverName:='MYSQL';
```

**Final code after Victorias solution, looks so:**

```
procedure TMeConnectForm.edExit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try
    MainForm.MyTrinityConnection.DriverName:='MySQL';
    MainForm.MyTrinityConnection.Params.AddPair('Server', edServer.Text);
    MainForm.MyTrinityConnection.Params.AddPair('Port', edPort.Text);
    MainForm.MyTrinityConnection.Params.AddPair('Database', edmDatabase.Text);
    MainForm.MyTrinityConnection.Params.AddPair('User_Name', edUsername.Text);
    MainForm.MyTrinityConnection.Params.AddPair('Password', edPassword.Text);
  except
    ActiveControl := Sender as TWinControl;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Yes. You could also just double-click MyTrinityConnection on the design form and set values there

Comment: Had there everything set up, but FireDAC was refusing to use it, so worked only after putting this code in correct place:
MainForm.MyTrinityConnection.DriverName:='MySQL';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Should I specify DriverName for my connection?

Yes, you have to, if that connection object does not have driver yet specified.

### 2. How to setup connection definition parameters?

Your translation is wrong. You are just repetitively calling [**Open**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomConnection.Open) method, passing every time a single connection definition parameter (what's more, values you are passing are part of Delphi statements). That is not how it's supposed to work.

If you wanted to use the [**Open**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomConnection.Open) method to specify connection definition parameters, you would have to pass there a fully qualified connection string.

Well, to specify connection definition parameters separately you could either do so in a name value pair way through the [**Params**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomConnection.Params) collection (see [**Connection Definition Parameters**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Connect_to_MySQL_Server_(FireDAC)#Connection_Definition_Parameters) for descriptions), for example:

```
FDConnection1.Params.Clear;
FDConnection1.Params.AddPair('Server', edServer.Text);
FDConnection1.Params.AddInt('Port', StrToIntDef(edPort.Text, 3306));
FDConnection1.Params.AddPair('Database', edmDatabase.Text);
FDConnection1.Params.AddPair('User_Name', edUsername.Text);
FDConnection1.Params.AddPair('Password', edPassword.Text);
```

Optionally, you could do the same through the specific MySQL implementation of [**Params**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomConnection.Params) collection, **TFDPhysMySQLConnectionDefParams** (this class you can remember from my [**last answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950615/8041231)), e.g.:

```
uses
  FireDAC.Phys.MySQLWrapper;

var
  MySQLDef: TFDPhysMySQLConnectionDefParams;
begin
  MySQLDef := TFDPhysMySQLConnectionDefParams(FDConnection1.Params);
  MySQLDef.Server := edServer.Text;
  MySQLDef.Port := StrToIntDef(edPort.Text, 3306);
  MySQLDef.Database := edmDatabase.Text;
  MySQLDef.UserName := edUsername.Text;
  MySQLDef.Password := edPassword.Text;
end;
```

For generic reading about connection definitions refer to the [**Defining Connection**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Defining_Connection_(FireDAC)) topic.

Comment: Thank you. Posted also working code so anyone can use that info.

Comment: You're welcome! Anyway, it's not needed to `Clear` the parameters if you change the `DriverName` as it changes the internal collection. So either `Clear` or change the `DriverName` ;-)